# Why are json.dumps() and json.loads() yielding unicode string?

Tags: python, json, unicode

> {'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 13, 35, 11), 'tweet':
>   "RT @KKRiders: Mavi to bowl the first ball of #Qualifier2. Saha on
>   strike. Let's go!\n\n#SRHvKKR #TeesraVaar #KKRHaiTaiyaar", 'id':
>   1000007371131764736, 'sequence': 1}

This is my string, I need it in json.

```
def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()
messageRead = json.dumps(message.value, default = myconverter)
messageRead = json.loads(messageRead)
print messageRead
print type(messageRead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not valid. To fix this, modify your string first:

- `datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 13, 35, 11)` is not a valid string. You can read pass it as a string, and parse it after loading.
- remove `\n`
- replace `'` with `"` (Python supports `'`, but JSON does not afaik)
- `\'` is also not allowed in JSON

Your string could look like this in order to be read:

> {     "created_at": "datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 13, 35, 11)",
> "tweet": "RT @KKRiders: Mavi to bowl the first ball of #Qualifier2.
> Saha on strike. Let's go!#SRHvKKR #TeesraVaar #KKRHaiTaiyaar",    "id":
> 1000007371131764736,  "sequence": 1 }

To check if your json is valid, use: https://jsonlint.com/

See the JSON RFC here to know what JSON supports: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159

Answer (score 1):

That's the way how [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#module-json) works in python2.7. 
The simplest way is to switch to [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#module-json). In case if you want to stick to the python2.7 you can use the object_pairs_hook.

```
import datetime
import json


message = {
   'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 13, 35, 11),
   'tweet': "RT @KKRiders: Mavi to bowl the first ball of #Qualifier2. Saha on strike. Let's go!\n\n#SRHvKKR #TeesraVaar #KKRHaiTaiyaar",
   'id': 1000007371131764736,
   'sequence': 1}
def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()

def object_pairs_hook(pairs):
    new_pairs = []
    for key, value in pairs:
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            try:
                value = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            except:
                value = value.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(key, unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        new_pairs.append((key, value))
    return dict(new_pairs)


messageRead = json.dumps(message, default = myconverter)
messageRead = json.loads(messageRead, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook)
print messageRead
```

Be aware that you have to modify the object_pairs_hook if you want it to work with lists and dictionaries as values